# How to efficiently loop over large data in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I currently have a large XML document that I am looping over using a simple `for` loop with the maximum set to the total number of products. During this loop the data is saved to a MySQLi database with insert queries.

Whilst running this the number of products saved per second drops off from around 3000 at first steadily dropping until it stops completely. I have increased the timeouts on the server and in Firefox and never see the full loop complete.

Is there something I am doing wrong with the loop, or variables or other timeouts that I have overlooked?

Comment: If you do not show us your loop code, there is hardly anything we can do to help

Comment: Using transactions? Commit them in 'batches' every  few hundred inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the actual looping isn't the problem.

Try for example building a single query in your loop that inserts everything and execute that once after the loop. Also if you have the data in a file you can use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

See here for more:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html